# How to stick icon to bottom of screen from within iFrame with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, iframe, sticky

I have an iFrame within a page and it has a chat-icon that should stick to the bottom of the screen (but of course it will have to remain in the iFrame when scrolled out of the view).

The iFrame stretches outside the main viewport and as it seems, the iFrame is only aware of the bottom of its own document/viewport which in my example resides below the bottom of the browser window. It is not aware of the bottom of the parent page which in this case is the bottom of the browser window..

The question is simply, is there a way to get this to work with CSS only from within the iFrame? I do have the option to post messages with i.e. page height down to the iFrame. I am trying to avoid Javascript solution to position the icon manually on scroll event, due to its flickeryness...

[image: iFrame in blue, chat icon to stick to bottom of screen while iFrame is visible]

Comment: Plus 1 for a very useful visual demo, as well as knowing to use the term viewport.

Comment: I think you will want to use a CSS class called sticky and set the position as fixed, your CSS needs to be triggered inside the iframe, ill send you a cute demo

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any way to do this in a CSS only fashion as the iframe is going to be completely unaware of the larger page (and that page's viewport) because it's own viewport is the bounds of the iframe itself, and the screen.

I think the only way to do this is with javascript using `postMessage` to pass the viewport dimensions down into the iframe where you can adjust the `bottom` value. To avoid flickering, add a short `transition` to the icon CSS so it slides into the correct place.